# Does a customer community plus user have default access to the account their contact is under?

Tags: customer-community

I'm trying to set up our Customer Community so our Customer Community users can see only their own Account record, along with related Assets.

Thing is, my OWD settings for external users has Accounts set to "Private", so I assumed my CC users wouldn't be able to see any until explicitly shared with them (via manual sharing, sharing rules, etc).

But when testing, it looks like my CC users can see their own Accounts by default when granted access to the Account tab or the search bar. (**edit**: by 'their own' Accounts I mean the account that a CC user exists as a contact under)

Do CC users have access to their own account records by default? Or am I missing something in my sharing settings?

**edit:** I'm realizing the fact that we have Customer Community Plus licenses might be relevant here, since they apparently follow the same sharing rules as internal users. However, I still don't see how the CC user should have visibility into their own account record?

Answer (score 1):

Private (in the context of Salesforce) means: only access to records that users own. So yes, if the OWD settings for external users is set to Private, the CC/CC+ uers will have access to their own Accounts.

Comment: To clarify, by 'their own accounts' I mean the CC user exists as a contact under that Account, not that the CC user is the Account Owner. But you're saying that any contacts that are made CC users will be able to see the account record they are kept under?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed implicitly granted by Salesforce:

> Account and case access—An account’s portal user has Read Only access
>   to the parent account and to all of the account’s contacts.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sharing_across_objects.htm